# Filtering records results in undefined method when category_id is provided

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, filtering

I've got a problem with filtering function in my app. Please enter here:
http://leszczyna.wzks.uj.edu.pl/12_stolarski/events_for_seniors/pl/events?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=Warszawa&date=02-06-2015

Search works fine, but when I try to filter by categories (left panel) then I get error:

> undefined method `category_id'

What is more, if you change category_id in link for category_whatever, then the error disappear (but filtering still doesn't work). **Does anybody know why the error appears?**

Here is the code:

**Category model**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
end
```

**Event model**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Filterable
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :category
end
```

**Events controller (index action)**

```
def index
  if params[:search] && params[:date] && @city
    date = params[:date].to_date
    @events = @city.events.filter(
        params.slice(
            :category_id, 
            :start_date, 
            :cost)
    )
    @categories = get_categories(@events)
  end
end
```

**Filter funtcion** (from http://www.justinweiss.com/blog/2014/02/17/search-and-filter-rails-models-without-bloating-your-controller/):

```
module Filterable
extend ActiveSupport::Concern

module ClassMethods
  def filter(filtering_params)
    results = self.where(nil)
    filtering_params.each do |key, value|
      results = results.public_send(key, value) if value.present?
    end
    results
  end
end
end
```

**Categories panel**

```
<div class="panel-body">
<ul>
  <% @categories.each do |category| %>
      <li><%= link_to category.name, events_path(
                              :search => params[:search],
                              :date => params[:date],
                              :category_id => category.id
                      )
      %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your search tries:

```
@city.events.category_id
```

and this doenst work. you have the same result with an other parameter like cost. your goal is to use something like this:

```
@city.events.where(category_id: category_id)
```

the filter doenst work for relation.

best

edit:

one way to solve:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events do
    def filter(key,value)                                                       
      where("#{key}=?",value)                                                   
    end
  end

  def filtered_events params                                                    
    result = events                                             
    sliced_params(params).each do |key, value|                                  
      result = result.filter(key,value)                                         
    end                                                                         
    result                                                                      
  end                                                                           

private                                                                       

  def sliced_params params                                                      
    params.slice(:category_id, :start_date, :cost)                              
  end 
end
```

and then you can call

```
@events = @city.filtered_events(params)
```

Comment: To tell the truth I have no idea how to make it works, can you suggest something? Or maybe it would be better if i used search gem?